# How to get Top sample row along with Meta columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have script which give  information about DB Name, Table Name, Column Name, Table Count  and Sample 1st Row.

Script  :

```
SELECT
  t.TABLE_SCHEMA  AS DB_NAME,
  t.TABLE_NAME,
  c.COLUMN_NAME,  
SUM(TABLE_ROWS) Tbl_Count,
 '' as sample_1st_Row
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_Name' AND t.TABLE_NAME  IN ('EMP_TBL','DEPT_TBL')
```

For example I'm getting Data as below for the script :

```
DB_NAME  TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME Tbl_Count  sample_1st_Row
EMP_DB   EMP_TBL     EMP_NAME     2000       
EMP_DB   DEPT_TBL    DEPT_NAME    50
```

Looking for output like this  :

```
DB_NAME  TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME Tbl_Count  sample_1st_Row
EMP_DB   EMP_TBL     EMP_NAME     2000       Mohan
EMP_DB   DEPT_TBL    DEPT_NAME    50         PHYSICS
```

In every table and for any of the column I'm looking for top 1 record as sample data in this script.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this one.

Comment: Instantiate your output as a temp table, create a dynamic sql to update the temp table , run the dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your query wouldn't run in the first place as INFORMATION_SCHEMA. TABLEs has no COLUMN_NAME

But you can use this

```
SELECT
  t.TABLE_SCHEMA  AS DB_NAME,
  t.TABLE_NAME,
  c.COLUMN_NAME,  
SUM(TABLE_ROWS) Tbl_Count,
MAX(CASE WHEN  t.TABLE_NAME = 'EMP_TBL' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'EMP_NAME' THEN (SELECT `EMP_NAME`  FROM `EMP_TBL` ORDER BY EMP_ID LIMIT 1) 
WHEN  t.TABLE_NAME = 'DEPT_TBL' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DEPT_NAME' THEN (SELECT `DEPT_NAME`  FROM `DEPT_TBL` ORDER BY DEPT_ID LIMIT 1) 
ELSE NULL
END) AS sample_1st_Row
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_Name' AND t.TABLE_NAME  IN ('EMP_TBL','DEPT_TBL')
AND c.COLUMN_NAME IN ('EMP_NAME','DEPT_NAME')
```

Which would give you something like

```
DB_NAME TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME Tbl_Count   sample_1st_Row
testdb  dept_tbl    DEPT_NAME   0           DEPName1
testdb  emp_tbl     EMP_NAME    0           Name1
```

The select for employee and department is only a example as you need to join there so that you get a employee form the department

Comment: I have multiple tables and multiple columns  @nbk..I don't want to be static

Comment: such automation is only possible if all tables and column a of the same pattern, but even then . Algorithms need fixed structures for sql